# Python sets, Monolingual exercise

Tags: python

I have an exercise in Grok learning, done in Python. Please the question and test case below:

After starting a new job, you observe that your workplace seems very multilingual. That is, a lot of people seem to be able to speak more than one language. You decide to do a survey of your coworkers to find out what languages they can all speak. Write a program to output the names of the people who can speak only one language (they are monolingual).

Read in one or more lines of input from the user. Each line will be a space separated list of the names of your coworkers who can speak a certain language. The name of the language will be the first thing on the line.

The first line of input will always be English, and you can assume that everyone at your workplace can speak English.

Here is an example interaction between you program and the user:

```
Line: English Tim Nicky James Tara John Ben
Line: German Nicky Tim
Line: Mandarin Tim John
Line: 
James is monolingual.
Tara is monolingual.
Ben is monolingual.
```

Your program can output the names of your monolingual coworkers in any order. If there are no monolingual coworkers, your program should output Everyone is multilingual!.

```
Line: English Boris Aleksei Dmitry Ivan
Line: Russian Dmitry Ivan Boris Aleksei
Line: 
Everyone is multilingual!
```

I've gone as far as this, but the problem with my code is that it only caters for 1, 2, 3 languages. It fails if more languages are added. 
Code:

```
masterList = []

supportedLanguages = []

userInput = input("Line: ")

while userInput != "":
    splitUserInput = userInput.split()  
    temporaryList = []  
    supportedLanguages.append(splitUserInput[0])
    temporaryList.append(splitUserInput[0])
    splitUserInput.remove(splitUserInput[0])    
    temporaryList.append(splitUserInput)
    masterList.append(temporaryList)
    userInput = input("Line: ")

namesMaster = []

for language in masterList:
    languageCopy = language
    languageCopy.remove(language[0])

    names = set()
    for name in languageCopy[0]:
        names.add(name)

    namesMaster.append(names)

if len(namesMaster) == 1:

    result = namesMaster[0]
    for name in result:
        print(name, " is monolingual.")

elif len(namesMaster) == 2:
    result = namesMaster[0].difference(namesMaster[1])
    print("Everyone is multilingual!")
else:   
    result = namesMaster[0].difference(namesMaster[1], namesMaster[2])

for name in result:
    print(name, " is monolingual.")
```

Comment: [Please condense your question so we can better help you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What error message are you getting on 4 or more languages?

Answer (score 1):

Utilizing a `defaultdict`:

Setup your variables:

```
from collections import defaultdict
masterList = defaultdict(list)
```

Use a `while` loop to loop your `input` and assigning each time to your variables as long as it's `true`.

```
while True:
  userInput = input("Line: ")
  if len(userInput) > 0:
    splitUserInput = userInput.split()
    lang = splitUserInput[0]
    # Everything after the first element is appended.
    for s in splitUserInput[1:]:
      masterList[s].append(lang)
  else:
    break
```

Iterate through your `defaultdict` to see if any keys have only one value assigned to them, and if not, print that everyone is multilingual.

```
all_multilingual = True
for name, langs in masterList.items():
  if len(langs) == 1:
    print(name + " is monolingual.")
    all_multilingual = False
if all_multilingual:
  print("Everyone is multilingual!")
```

Comment: @Codean Glad I could help. Please make sure to accept the answer if you're satisfied! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using only what has been learnt - this is the answer (its also the simplest)

```
monolingual = None

line = input('Line: ')
while line:
  line = line.split()
  names = set(line[1:])
  if monolingual is None:
    monolingual = names
  else:
    monolingual -= names
  line = input('Line: ')

if monolingual:
  for name in monolingual:
    print(name, 'is monolingual.')
else:
  print('Everyone is multilingual!')
```

Comment: Can you please explain this in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

In this Python Grok exercise the objective is to use sets:

```
a = {1, 2, 3}
b = {3, 4, 5}
print(a | b)  # Union
print(a & b)  # Intersection
print(a - b)  # Difference
print(b - a)  # Difference
print(a ^ b)  # Symmetric difference
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line = input("Line: ")
a = set(line.split()[1:])

line = input("Line: ")
while line:
      line = set(line.split()[1:])
      a = a -line
      line = input("Line: ")

if a:
      for person in a:
      print(person + ' is monolingual.')
else:
      print("Everyone is multilingual!")
```